# Creating a copy of a template in backbonejs

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js

I have the following Backbone View, which works fine the first time I load the view, I want to be able to render the template and increase the count by 1 each time i click on add. At the moment, clicking on add is just re-rendering the template with an increase in the count.

```
 app.FactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#facts-container',

    model:app.FactModel,

    template: _.template($("#facts").html()),

    events: {
        'click #add': 'addBlock',
        'click #delete': 'deleteBlock'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        var data = { count : counter };            
        this.$el.html(this.template(data),this);                        
        renderEditor();
        counter++;
    },

    addBlock: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template({ count: counter }),this);            
        renderEditor();
        counter++;
    },

    deleteBlock: function() {
        console.log('here');
    }

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    app.FactView = new app.FactView({});
});
```

Is there a way that I can add a new template under the already rendered template.

Here is what my template looks like

```
div.col-sm-12#facts-container  
      script(type="text/template" id="facts")         
         div.col-sm-8.col-sm-offset-1
            form.form-horizontal
              div.form-group
                  label.form-label.col-sm-2  Fact <%= count %>
                  div.col-sm-10  
                    input.form-control.fact(type='text',name='fact',placeholder='Fact') 
              div.form-group                  
                div.col-sm-12.summernote                  
          div.form-group
           div.col-sm-4
           div.col-sm-6.btn-group
               button.col-sm-4.btn.btn-warning#add 
                  | Add Another Fact
               button.col-sm-4.btn.btn-danger#delete 
                  | Delete Last Fact
               button.col-sm-4.btn.btn-success#next
                  | Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `this.$el.html`, use `this.$el.append`

If you are lucky, that is all you will need to change.  Otherwise, if you are looking for more control and more functionality in your templates, you will have to get more fancy.  For that, [ToDoMVC for Backbone](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/) is a great example.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider adding `counter` to `FactModel` and leveraging Backbone's Model events:

```
// ...

initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change:count", this.render);
    this.render();
},

addBlock: function () {
    this.model.set({
        count: this.model.get('count') + 1
    })
}

// ....
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xey9vget/1/)